# Parsing a text file with different types in C

Tags: c, parsing

I'm having some trouble when parsing a text file. Each line of the text has a name followed after three float values. All of them are separated by a blankspace. What I want is to store the name in a string and the numbers in an array. I know I have to read each line using fgets and then strtok but the thing is I don't understand how strtok works. Do I have to call strtok four times? How do I assign each "piece" to my variables ?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your own attempt, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: Create a struct, e.g. `struct values { char name[32]; float v1, v2, v3; }` then create an array of `struct values`. Read with `fgets()` and then parse with `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `strtok` will search for the given tokens in a string. You must call it until the it returns NULL.

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)
```

The first call is done passing the string (char*) as the argument `str` and the remaining times are done passing NULL, as this will define that it should keep looking for the next token from that point onwards.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char line[] = "name 1.45 2.55 3.65";

    char* name;
    double values[3] = { 0 };
    char* ptr = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    ptr = strtok(line, " "); // Search for the first whitespace

    if (ptr != NULL) // Whitespace found
    {
        /* 'line' is now a string with all the text until the whitespace,
           with terminating null character */

        name = calloc(1, strlen(line));
        strcpy(name, line);

        while ((i < 3) && (ptr != NULL))
        {
            ptr = strtok(NULL, " "); // Call 'strtok' with NULL to continue until the next whitespace
            
            if (ptr != NULL) // Whitespace found
            {
                /* 'ptr' has now the text from the previous token to the found whitespace,
                   with terminating null character */
                   
                values[i] = atof(ptr); // Convert to double
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    printf("%s %lf %lf %lf\n", name, values[0], values[1], values[2]);
}
```